How to refer to a local file on an Android phone (Moto G8 Powerlite Android 10)
I want to use Excel on my phone to enable me to click on any one of a list of tunes, and the intro to the tune is played.
I have the intros recorded and stored in storage/emulated/0/EasyVoiceRecorder/
and can play them from that location, but when using =hyperlink("file://storage/emulated/0/EasyVoiceRecorder/Yellowjacket.m4a","Yellowjacket)
I get the message " Sorry, we couldn't open this link. The link address may be invalid, or you may not have permission to open it."
Should I store the files in an Android/data/com......path somehow?
Thanks.

Possible duplicate for Excel specifically: Open local file from Excel Cell in Android (not answered yet, contained many failed cases). Related for the title: Local files revisited: Opening local HTML files (file:///path/to/file) in Chrome on Android 10.x.
